# App Crashes when MainActivity extended with FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

My android application crashes if my main activity is a FragmentActivity.

Any Ideas on how to fix this?

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
//...
}
```

Comment: Please post complete relevant code

Comment: make sure you have added http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html lib

Comment: What error do you get? Show the logcat...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I just needed to wrap my fragment in activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```